# Elasticsearch query by generic properties: keywords and numeric values

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this mapping in ES 7.9:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "cid": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "store": true
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "store": true
      },
      "a": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "attribute":{
            "type": "keyword"      
          },  
          "key": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "num": {
            "type": "float"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And some documents indexed like:

```
{
    "cid": "177",
    "id": "1",
    "a": [
        {
            "attribute": "tags",
            "key": [
                "heel",
                "thong",
                "low_heel",
                "economic"
            ]
        },
        {
            "attribute": "weight",
            "num": 15
        }
    ]
}
```

Basically, an object can have multiple attributes (`a` property array).

Those attributes can be different for each client. In this example, I have 2 types of attributes: `tag` and `weight`, however other documents could have other attributes like `vendor`, `size`, `power`, etc., so the model has to be generic enough to support beforehand unknown attributes.

An attribute can be a list of keywords (like `tags`) or a numeric value (like `weight`).

I need an ES query to fetch the documents `ids` with this pseudo-query:

`cid="177" and (tag="flat" or tag="heel") and tag="economic" and weight<20`

I managed to reach this query that seems to be working as expected:

```
{
    "_source": ["id"],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must" : [
                {"term" : { "cid" : "177" }},
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "a",
                        "query": {
                            "bool":{
                                "must":[
                                    {"term" : { "a.attribute": "tags"}},
                                    {"terms" : { "a.key": ["flat","heel"]}}       
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "a",
                        "query": {
                            "bool":{
                                "must":[
                                    {"term" : { "a.attribute": "tags"}},
                                    {"term" : { "a.key": "economic"}}       
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "a",
                        "query": {
                            "bool":{
                                "must":[
                                    {"term" : { "a.attribute": "weight" } },
                                    {"range": { "a.num": {"lt": 20} } }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }                 
            ]            
        }
    }
}
```

1. Is this query correct or I am getting the correct results by chance?
2. Is the query (or mapping) optimal or I should rethink something?
3. Can the query be simplified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The query is correct.
2. The mapping is great and the query is optimal.
3. While the query *can* be simplified:

```
{
  "_source": [
    "id"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "cid": "177"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "a",
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "a.attribute:tags AND ((a.key:flat OR a.key:heel) AND a.key:economic)"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "a",
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "a.attribute:weight AND a.num:<20"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

it'd be **less optimal** due to the fact that these `query_strings` would still need to be internally compiled into essentially the query DSL that you've got above. Plus you'd still be needing the two separate `nested` groups so... You're good to roll with what you've got.